# Upload file rest webservice

Tags: web-services, rest, file-upload, upload, jersey

I am using this code to upload a file

```
public class upload {
private static final String SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER = "C://Users/Marya/Desktop/uploaded/";
@Path(value ="upload/{path}")
public Response uploadFile(
    @PathParam("path") String path, InputStream uploadedInputStream)
{
    String fileName = SERVER_UPLOAD_LOCATION_FOLDER + "randomName.png";
    saveFile(uploadedInputStream, fileName);
    String output = "File saved to server location : " + fileName;
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
private void saveFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream, String serverLocation) {
    try {
        OutputStream outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        outpuStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(serverLocation));
        while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
            outpuStream.write(bytes, 0, read);
        }
        outpuStream.flush();
        outpuStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

this code is not working if I use this url : http://*****:8080/ConnectDataBase/rest/files/upload/C:/Users/Marya/Desktop/Capture.jpg ;

Are there any suggestions to this issue? Please help!

Comment: tyr this :
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932436/unable-to-upload-file-with-jersey/23933660#23933660][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932436/unable-to-upload-file-with-jersey/23933660#23933660